# Custom system font for a UIBarButtonItem in a toolbar for LaunchScreen.xib

Tags: ios, fonts, interface-builder

I am using the *Avenir Next* font (which is provided by iOS) in my app that I set up with the appearance API. I would like my LaunchScreen.xib to use it too so that the transition from launch screen to initial view controller is smooth.

I was able to use *Avenir Next* for the navigation bar in Interface Builder but I can’t find a way to set a font for a UIBarButtonItem inside a UIToolbar. The *Avenir Next* font is properly displaying in the navigation bar during launch screen time.

Since I need it for the launch screen I obviously can’t solve this problem by setting the font programmatically, it must be done in Interface Builder.

Is there a way to accomplish this, maybe by manually editing the LaunchScreen.xib file?

Comment: Does the font show up on Navigation Bar when launched ?
Asking because I think Launch Screens are launched apart from the app to be displayed and can't access app's other resources (such as custom fonts)

Comment: Yes, it displays properly. I edited my question to make it clear.

Comment: Would it suit you to use a UIBarButtonItem containing an UIButton ? Because you could then edit UIButton font, just tried and it works. I don't know if the appearance is exactly the same as a simple UIBarButtonItem with font customized by UIAppearance though…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `UIBarButtonItem` with a custom view. You can do that in a storyboard/xib just by dragging and dropping a view/button to your toolbar and it will create a `UIBarButtonItem` with the nested view.

The code will look like this:

```
<barButtonItem style="plain" id="AwC-sg-sT1">
    <view key="customView" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="4Z4-cp-rPM">
        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="33"/>
        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
    </view>
</barButtonItem>
```

Comment: Dragging a UIView in the toolbar did not work for me, the view would snap back into the object library. But pasting that xml snippet in my LaunchScreen.xib did work and the view appeared in Interface Builder!

Answer (score -4):

Initial thoughts would be to subclass UIBarButton Item. Override the font property, with IBInspectable and set it to the Avenir Next font as default. But I cannot test this currently, so I do not know if this will work properly.

Comment: LaunchScreen can't contain custom classes.

Answer (score -4):

Straight from one of my projects:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UINavigationBar class], nil] 
     setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                              NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"YOUR FONT" size:21.f],
                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]
                              } forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: From original question : "Since I need it for the launch screen I obviously can’t solve this problem by setting the font programmatically, it must be done in Interface Builder."